# Easy Desktop Remote with Xubuntu, Android and Fail2ban protection

Tags: xubuntu, android, remote-desktop, fail2ban

I have switched from Windows to Xubuntu 22.04 last days and now i am searching some easy setup for desktop remote. The years before I always used Windows RDP which was not so easy. Windows did not have any bruteforce protection in RDP which cost much time to setup a solution.

My needs are:

- Desktop Remote controll in Android
- Bruteforce protection with fail2ban (hopefully without setup f2b to this remote service because f2b is always very hard to configuration)
- Compatible with public IPv6 network
- Open source software

On desktop PCs i am using x11-forwarding via ssh which works very good. Because it uses default ssh I dont need to customize fail2ban, which is very very great!

Now I have search for some android app which uses X11-Forwarding in ssh but it seems that there is nothing.

So what could be a good solution? Are there any apps on android which working well and dont need so much configurarion (firewall, f2b, etc.)